# Trigger Goal Not Associated with Content Item?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

Ultimately, I'm trying to track individual links in an ECM (2.1) email.

I recently found the "sc_trk" querystring variable in the [Engagement Analytics Configuration Reference Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/engagement_analytics_configuration_reference_sc66-a4.pdf), which should allow me to trigger a goal from the querystring.  So I've updated my links to include "?sc_trk=xxxxxx", but I am not seeing the goals being triggered when users click on the email links.

I have deployed the goals, but I have not associated them with specific content items.  In order to trigger the goal, it doesn't have to be associated with content, does it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is definitely: yes, your goal does not need to be associated with content to be triggered.

As to why your goals is not being triggered I'd look into the RedirectUrlPage.aspx that ECM uses for its links. Send a campaign out to yourself and study the generated URLs, they go to a page called RedirectUrlPage (where ECM handles tracking some things) which you can find under the /sitecore directory. Possibly your querystring is not being passed on when this redirect happens.

Comment: Also of course make sure your goal is published and in final workflow state, but I guess you double checked that already.

Comment: Good idea with the redirect page.  I'll look there.